# Kaminari generates string instead of html in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari, slim-lang

I'm using Rails 4.2.1, Kaminari 0.16.3 and slim as my template language.

In development mode everything is okay. The pagination navigation is generated correctly, but when I run server in production mode, `= paginate @articles` generates a string instead of html. So it's escape tags and show them like regular text

```
<span class="page current">1</span><span class="page"><a rel="next" href="/airsoft-blog/airsoft-gadgets-and-ammunition-reviews?page=2">2</a></span><span class="next"><a rel="next" href="/airsoft-blog/airsoft-gadgets-and-ammunition-reviews?page=2">старее</a></span>
```

It's running on a thin server and Ruby 2.2.1. This happens the first time.

Comment: did you try `= raw paginate(@articles)` (could fix it wouldn't explain the problem though)

Comment: See my answer here. I had slightly different problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366509/kaminari-generates-string-instead-of-html/34366610#34366610

Comment: Same bug here. How did you manage this?

Comment: @coding addicted  my problem was in config/locales/ru.yml . with text i also have some html icon('next <span class="icon"></span>'). after i remove html tags from locales, all works correctly.

Comment: Ok thanks for the response

Comment: @codingaddicted answer bellow from Yury is nearly the true - so check strings of ruby which contains html

Comment: Yes this was my fix for the moment, but I'll go over my locales files too.

Comment: @codingaddicted also check every kaminari helper with .html_safe. problems can appear if you manually rewrite view partials of kaminari from erb to haml/slim

Answer (score 3):

Try this (double equal sign):

```
== paginate @articles
```

Kaminari generates html, and it should be used as html in the template, not as string, therefor you need either `raw` or a `==` to output it.

Answer (score 0):

my problem was with config/locales/ru.yml

bad(not working):

```
 pagination:
  previous: "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left'></span>"
```

good(work correctly):

```
 pagination:
  previous: 'older post'
```

this is not kaminari bug, but only my fault. also now i think it's a bad practice if you add html inside localisation files