# Kaminari generates string instead of html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari, slim-lang

There was question like this in november, but no anwers was given.
[Kaminari generates string instead of html in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521660/kaminari-generates-string-instead-of-html-in-production)
And no feedback from author, lack of reputation does not give me the opportunity to ask question there, also my problem a little bit different too.
I'm using Rails 4.2.4, Kaminari 0.16.3 and slim as my template language.

The pagination navigation is generated correctly, but = paginate @articles generates ALMOST a string instead of html. So it's escape tags and show them like regular text (except first UL element)

```
<ul class=\"pagination\">&lt;li class=&quot;active&quot;&gt;&lt;a remote=&quot;false&quot;&gt;1&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a rel=&quot;next&quot; href=&quot;/?locale=en&amp;amp;page=2&quot;&gt;2&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a rel=&quot;next&quot; href=&quot;/?locale=en&amp;amp;page=2&quot;&gt;Next › &lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/?locale=en&amp;amp;page=2&quot;&gt;Last &amp;raquo;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;</ul>
```

It's running on a thin server and ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295). This happens the first time.

I tried next:
==  paginate @articles
raw(paginate @articles)
htmlentities gem
CGI

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. I found The problem (but i didn't recognise causes, so ...)
in your _paginator.html.slim partial? change all '=' to '==' 
It helped me. But still I think it is not a wise solution.

```
= paginator.render do
    ul.pagination
        == first_page_tag unless current_page.first?
        == prev_page_tag unless current_page.first?
        - each_page do |page|
          - if page.left_outer? || page.right_outer? || page.inside_window?
            == page_tag page
          - elsif !page.was_truncated?
            == gap_tag
        == next_page_tag unless current_page.last?
        == last_page_tag unless current_page.last?
```